# What is the excel equivalent of a COUNTIF with WILDCARD formula in Tableau?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, tableau-api

I'm working on a Tableau table where I'd like to:

1. Isolate specific string records in a dimension; then
2. Count the instances that a specific string appears in that dimension (so all the records).  A record may have multiple but different texts within.

Let's say my Dimension is called "Person Type" and I have 5 records with these respective values:
Employee, Visitor, Employee; Visitor, Applicant, Visitor; Applicant

I understand that I could first create a filter on the dimension to only show the singular record types: Employee, Visitor, Applicant, but where I'm having trouble is creating a calculation that looks at all the records and counts the instances that the word "Employee" is present in and so forth.  In excel, a COUNTIF formula with a text wildcard handles this.

Here's an excel screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDOEB.png)

Edit:  Tried a calculation that was pretty close to the solution.  For some reason it's not counting Applicant, when there's clearly two instances of it.  anyone have any idea's on how to improve the calculation?

```
    IF CONTAINS([Person Types],'Employee') THEN "Employee"

ELSEIF CONTAINS([Person Types],'Visitor') THEN "Visitor"

ELSEIF CONTAINS([Person Types],'Applicant') THEN "Applicant"
END
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6gZq.jpg)
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l7Pg.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Contains function in your LOD which operates like a wild card `*X*` in Excel.

So something like:

`{ FIXED [NEWFIELD]: SUM(INT(CONTAINS([PERSON],"Employee"))) }`

The code

```
    IF CONTAINS([Person Types],'Employee') THEN "Employee"

ELSEIF CONTAINS([Person Types],'Visitor') THEN "Visitor"

ELSEIF CONTAINS([Person Types],'Applicant') THEN "Applicant"
END
```

will not correctly count `"Applicant"` if there is an `"Employee"` or a "Visitor" since they will take precedence (each if is tested in sequence). So for example `"Visitor; Applicant"` will return `"Visitor"`

Also `CONTAINS` is case-sensitive so you might want to convert to all upper case to ensure that any subtle case variances are matched.

```
IF CONTAINS(UPPER([Person Types]),"APPLICANT") THEN "Applicant"
```

Comment: Hi Neil - Thank you for your response.  Quick question.  Can a LOD be applied to one dimension?  Where would this "Newfield" come from?

Comment: The new field is the one you are creating.

The critical part is the (SUM...) the PERSON column is the one you are trying to count on.

Comment: For this solution, one may have to manually create the values for first field!

Answer (score 0):

I recreated a sample like you have shown in your screenshot for a demonstration (it is always advised to copy and paste some rows of data directly in the code)

Steps (Tableau Desktop) It is though easier in Prep-

- In the `data source` pane after connecting your data, click a down arrow on the `person type` field and click `split`
- Two new field will be automatically created (given that maximum person types in one record is 2) or more rows will be created.  (It is highly advised to have Tableau Prep) In tableau prep you can directly PIVOT these fields.  See method [here](https://interworks.com/blog/kwagner/2018/12/27/split-and-pivot-your-data-with-tableau-prep/#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Connect%20to%20data,columns%20using%20a%20Pivot%20step.).  But pivoting on calculated fields is not there in Tableau Desktop
- Union the data with itself n (=2 here in this case) number of times. See GIF for help

[image]

- create a calculated field say `person types` (I added a `s` intentionally to differentiate) with the following calculation

```
// A single person_type for each row.
CASE [Table Name]
WHEN "Sheet1" THEN [Person Type - Split 1]
WHEN "Sheet11" THEN [Person Type - Split 2]
END
```

Excluding `null` values you can create your desired views

[image]

**Needless to say that you have to change values of `[table name]` as per your case in the calculated field**

Comment: Hi AnilGoyal - Thank you for your response.  I was able to re-create your process and end up with the same results.  Would this method work for records that have more than two texts in them?  For example, a record with three person types: Employee; Visitor; Applicant.  Instead of the current 1 or 2.  If so, how would the split method and calculation accommodate for that?

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Please upvote and accept the answer for future reference as usually desired on SO. For n>2 say 3 you have to union your table three times and modify case statement accordingly. Rest is same.